# Inverse Distance Weighting algorithm in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, distance, latitude-longitude

I have a large amount of data associated with latitude/longitude in a database (currently housed in MS SQL Server).

For the data, I would like to use SQL to calculate the distance from a user derived lat long and then use this distance in an [inverse distance weighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting) (IDW) algorithm. I want to do this in SQL rather than inside of a GIS because the data is quite honestly large and complex and I have a tendency to not rely on ArcGIS to do these calculations.

I was wondering if there are SQL implementations of IDW algorithm out there that some could share.

As stated in the link above, IDW is NOT a distance calculator rather the IDW algorithm is an INTERPOLATION function which uses distance as an input.  Please remove the duplication status.

Comment: Someone out there might have a SQLCLR implementation; outside of that I'm not sure what you'll get.

Comment: If this were a question like "i'm having x problem w/ this IDW implementation" then it would fit here nicely.  Asking for a library however is off topic for SO.  Stackexchange has a very nice [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) site however that may be closer to what you need.

Comment: I do not believe I asked for a library - I asked for SQL code.  Also,I specifically asked for a non-GIS solution.

Comment: I don't know about IDW. Are you asking for an algorithm that calculates the **nearest latitude and longitude pairs (proximity search)** based on the given latitude and longitude pair? If so, create a new question; I'll post the sql script.

Comment: If you do not know about IDW why respond ?  This question is not a distance calculation question and it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: I am not sure why this was closed as a duplicate. @user918967 was not asking about haversine distances. Unfortunately I cannot answer the question but IDW is just a weighted average where the weights the weights are the inverse of the distances with a user-selected parameter "p". So  `SUM(1/POWER(distance,p)*value)/SUM(1/POWER(distance,p) AS idw_weighted_value` will work